# How do I get Punch (Cocktail) to hoot into Visual Studio's internal Composition Container?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, mef, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, devforce

I am trying to use DevForce's Punch in my Visual Studio 2017 Extensibility (VSIX) application. The MEF Exports of my VSIX are NOT being recognized. It seems becuase VS uses it's own composition container. How can I intergrate Visual Studio's internal composition container catalog to Cocktail's composition container?

For example, if I get a reference to Visual Studio's Default Catalog :

```
var dte2 = (DTE2)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE));
var sp = new ServiceProvider(dte2 as Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider);
var container = sp.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.SComponentModel)) as Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.IComponentModel;

var catalog = container.DefaultCatalog;
```

How do I add that catalog to Punch?

Or should I get access to Visual Studio's DefaultExportProvider or DefaultCompositionService?

Not sure which way to go. Any direction or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: You might be able to use the DevForce CompositionHost which underlies Punch extensibility.  You can directly add a catalog using CompositionHost.Add(catalog).  If the timing of this doesn't work out you can also try subclassing the Punch CocktailMefBootStrapper class to override the PrepareCompositionCatalog method.  More info on this at http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/cocktail-application-bootstrapper.

Comment: Thanks Ken.  I will try subclassing CocktailMefBootStrapper and post back my results :-)

Comment: Hi Ken, You Rock! I was able to get everything working by doing the following:    protected override ComposablePartCatalog PrepareCompositionCatalog()
        {
            AssemblyCatalog asmCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            CompositionHost.Add(asmCatalog);

            return base.PrepareCompositionCatalog();
        }. THANKS!!!!

Comment: @MrTouya, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if possible, you could share your solution as an answer, and then mark it later, so it could help other community members who get the same issue as yours. Thanks for your sharing:)

Comment: Hi Kim, Thanks again for helping out. I discovered a related issue. It seems I also need to get Devforce's [InterfaceExport]. Becuase of VS internal handling of MEF, anything marked with the custom attribute is ignored. Is there a facility within in Caliburn.Micro or Devforce that I can override to manually get the [InterfaceExport] and add it to VS as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get Punch within Visual Studio to recognize MEF Exports by implementing the following code:

```
protected override ComposablePartCatalog PrepareCompositionCatalog() 
{ 
        AssemblyCatalog asmCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); 
        CompositionHost.Add(asmCatalog); 
        return base.PrepareCompositionCatalog(); 
}
```

Thanks again Kim for your help! 
PS Sorry for getting your name wrong. I just realized that you are THE Kim Johnson from IdeaBlade!!

Comment: You could mark it as the answer, thanks for sharing your solution here again.